# How do I add non managed chef nodes to be handle by chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I have existing servers (not bootstrapped by chef) and I want to remove some files on all these servers. I don't want to use a shell script but use chef instead. Should I install chef-client on each of those servers.

This is not about provisioning. More like you join a company and see existing servers and want to register those servers in chef so you can perform daily maintenance like start and stop services, cleaning up space.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can use `knife bootstrap` to install chef-client and connect it to your Chef Server if you already have one, or use `knife-solo` if you don't want to use a Chef Server. Chef only does what its recipes tell it, do you can use it for as much or as little as you want.

Comment: My servers have limited access, no root access. Can I bootstrap  the chef-client  with no root access? I only have access to my home directory /usr/home/myApps

Comment: Technically yes, but all the precompiled packages for chef-client and chefdk require root access to run the native package manager in the simple case. The packages are definitely not designed to be relocatable either, so you'll probably have to compile and install all the components yourself. This is very doable, but far from the easy path.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to perform some tasks from time to time on the machines, then Chef is good but not the best choice. The point of Chef is that it runs as a service on target node and makes sure the node is in correct state.

I would recommend looking into *[ansible](http://www.ansible.com/get-started?&__hssc=&__hstc&hsCtaTracking=5f754c20-f6b9-446a-9a66-5c0131cf21ce|5feefe51-9ea0-496e-9f07-3cc63c158da3)*. It does not have anything to be installed on target machine and also no root privileges are needed. You just have to have ssh access to the machines from your workstation.